# Element with clear:both has floating sibling elements on both sides of it

Tags: css, css-float

My understanding was that a div with clear:both; would not have any floating  sibling divs positioned on either side of it. In this example I have 3 sibling, left floating divs inside of a container div with overflow:auto. There's enough room for all of them to be side by side.

Link to jsfiddle below.

When I apply clear:both to the middle div it moves it to the next line (as expected) however the div to the right of it also moves down and remains on it's right side despite that area being cleared. I'd expect each div to be on a new line.

[image]

Further more if I just add clear:right; to the middle div it remains where it is (in line with the div to its left - as expected) and the div to its right also stays beside it. I would have though the right div would have moved to a new line.

[image]

This behaviour seems to contradict what clear is supposed to achieve by preventing floating sibling elements from being beside each other. Can anyone explain this?

jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/2tfgwmek/1/

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="left">Left Div<br>float: left; </div>
    <div class="middle">Middle Div<br>float: left; clear:both; </div>
    <div class="right">Right Div<br> float:left </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
   width:300px;
   overflow:auto;
   border:solid 2px black;
}

.container > div {
   width:90px; height:90px;
   border:solid 1px red;
   background:grey;
   float:left;
   color:white;
}

.middle {
   clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clear` only applies to elements that precede the element you've applied `clear` to.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear

> The clear CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared) below them. The clear property applies to both floating and non-floating elements.

And the `left` or `right` (or `both`) values refer to the direction of the float on the previous element. So here, the only float you can clear on the middle div is the one that preceded it, and that element was floated left, so `clear: left` is all you can use that will affect the layout. `clear: right` won't do anything in your example.

If there were 2 divs before the middle one, and one was floated left, and the other right, then you could use `clear: left` or `clear: right` (or `clear: both`) to affect the layout.